# Array Difference from Database

Tags: php, arrays

In `$imeiserial` I have `123,222,333` in `$imeitransferserial` I have `123,222`. I just want to show the value of the difference between those 2 array, I use this code but it give me error: 
`Array to string conversion` what did I do wrong? or I need more conversion in this function?

```
$imei=$row["IMEI_MX"];
$imeiserial = explode(',', $imei);
$imeitransfer=$row2["IMEI_MX"];
$imeitransferserial = explode(',', $imeitransfer);

$a1=array($imeiserial);
$a2=array($imeitransferserial);

$result= array_diff_assoc($a1,$a2);
```

Comment: Confirm that `$imei` and `$imeitransfer` are strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `$a1 = array` assignment is superfluous. Just leave it:

```
$a1 = $imeiserial; // no need to put inside an array
$a2 = $imeitransferserial; // once exploded, they are already an array
```

And using `*_assoc` flavor doesn't make sense, your keys are numeric, just use `array_diff`:

```
$result = array_diff($a1,$a2);
```

Comment: it gave me error like this Notice: Undefined variable: imeitransferserial in C:\xampp\htdocs\excel\tryy.php on line 65

Warning: array_diff(): Argument #2 is not an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\excel\tryy.php on line 66

Comment: @CarlosJhonmanlulu  it's your responsibility to check `$imei=$row["IMEI_MX"];
$imeiserial = explode(',', $imei);
$imeitransfer=$row2["IMEI_MX"];
$imeitransferserial = explode(',', $imeitransfer);` all these variable are set or not. go and check by printing them out

Comment: @CarlosJhonmanlulu its funny how its undefined, that variable name came form your question https://3v4l.org/6LXvS

Comment: it gave me error like this Array to string conversion on outputing the result