# how will i implode the result of array_diff

Tags: php

> How will i separated by comma the result of array_diff i tried this code but it gave me Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array give
>   Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
   <?php
    $row['IMEI_MX'] = '123,222,333';
    $row2["IMEI_MX"] = '123,222';
    $imei = $row["IMEI_MX"];
    $imeiserial = explode(',', $imei);
    $imeitransfer = $row2["IMEI_MX"];
    $imeitransferserial = explode(',', $imeitransfer);

    $a1 = $imeiserial;
     $a2 = $imeitransferserial;

    $result = array_diff($a1,$a2);
   $separate = implode(' ', $result);
foreach($separate as $is){

    echo $is;

}
```

Comment: So many unnecessary variables ...!!! Try removing `$separate = implode(',', $result);` line and iterate `$result` in foreach()

Comment: unable to pass the sting variable in foreach  foreach($separate as $is){ } to  foreach($result as $is) { }

Comment: try to read this http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array Difference from Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38494972/array-difference-from-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to show the `values` of `first string` which are not in `second string` .

Tried this one

```
    <?php
    $row['IMEI_MX'] = '123,222,333,444';
    $row2["IMEI_MX"] = '123,222';
    $imei = $row["IMEI_MX"];
    $imeiserial = explode(',', $imei);
    $imeitransfer = $row2["IMEI_MX"];
    $imeitransferserial = explode(',', $imeitransfer);

    $a1 = $imeiserial;
     $a2 = $imeitransferserial;

    $result = array_diff($a1,$a2);
  $sting = implode(',',$result);
   echo  $sting;
?>
```

It will result as

```
333,444
```

Comment: i want the result is 333,444

Answer (score 0):

Use implode, it is the opposite function, you are using.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\excel\tryy.php on line 68

Comment: In a foreach, a array is needed. What do you want now? $separate as an array or as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Use implode to get comma separated array values

```
$separate = implode(',', $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode is used for converting a string into array, while specifying the delimiter. Implode is the opposite one - you specify the glue for converting an array to string.

In your case, you don't need an explode after array_diff, because the result is itself an array. There's no need to convert anything. So, you just need to remove that line before the foreach:

```
foreach($result as $is){
    echo $is;
}
```

When you use implode in the foreach, it throughs an error, because you're trying to loop through a string (the result of the implode operation) and the foreach operation expects an array.

**UPDATE:**

Follow the above code if you want to echo all items of the resulting array. If you want to display the array as a string, separated by comma, you need to go with implode but dismis the foreach after.

```
$separate = implode(',', $result);
echo $separate;
```

Comment: its still not giving me the separation by comma that i wanted :(

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you want to convert the array to a string then you can't do a foreach at the end. In that case, you will simply need to do the implode and stop the script.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Your request is very confusing, you need to make clear what you try to achieve in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

try this no need foreach just use [implode](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp)

```
<?php


$row['IMEI_MX'] = '123,222,333,444';
$row2["IMEI_MX"] = '123,222';
$imei = $row["IMEI_MX"];
$imeiserial = explode(',', $imei);
$imeitransfer = $row2["IMEI_MX"];
$imeitransferserial = explode(',', $imeitransfer);

$a1 = $imeiserial;
 $a2 = $imeitransferserial;

$result = array_diff($a1,$a2);

echo implode(',',$result);

?>
```